# How do I set up PowerShell as my SmartGit "Open Git-Shell" command?

Tags: powershell, smartgit

I have tried setting up `PowerShell` as my "`Open Git-Shell`" option with no success. In the Command field I have set the following options:

**Command:**

```
powershell.exe
```

**Arguments:**

```
-noexit -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command "cd '${filePath}'"
```

This will launch PowerShell in non-interactive mode (i.e.: the process is running in task manager, but the UI isn't visible). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when invoking the same from command line?

Comment: When I run the command directly in the command line (cmd.exe), PowerShell runs within the command window and changes the directory to the specified directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around with using `cmd.exe` to invoke `PowerShell` for "`Open Git-Shell`" in `SmartGit`. I was able to get the desired result with the following:

**Command:**

```
cmd.exe
```

**Arguments:**

```
/c start powershell.exe -noexit -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command "cd '${filePath}'"
```